# How to set $jobname from within latexmkrc depending on latexmk command-line argument for TeX engine?

Tags: latexmk

I have a pdfLaTeX/XeLaTeX file with `iftex` for compilation with either engine. I want to use `latexmk` to compile the source with `-pdf`/`-pdflatex` or `-pdfxe`/`-xelatex` options.

The goal is to get PDF output with different names `<basename>-pdftex.pdf` or `<basename>-xetex.pdf` via setting `$jobname` in `latexmkrc`. How can I check engine option used in latexmk invocation?

It seems that the command-line option does not set `$pdf_mode`. If I call `latexmk -pdf`, I still get `$pdf_mode = 0`. The documentation describes variable `$rule` but it is uninitialized when used in `latexmkrc`.

The solution can be to set `-jobname` in `$pdflatex`/`$xelatex` variables, but I wanted a somewhat more general approach with modification of the intended variable:

```perl
if ($pdf_mode == 0) { $jobname = "%A-tex"; }
elsif ($pdf_mode == 1) { $jobname = "%A-pdftex"; }
elsif ($pdf_mode == 2) { $jobname = "%A-ps2pdf"; }
elsif ($pdf_mode == 3) { $jobname = "%A-dvipdf"; }
elsif ($pdf_mode == 4) { $jobname = "%A-luatex"; }
elsif ($pdf_mode == 5) { $jobname = "%A-xetex"; }
else { $jobname = "%A-UNKNOWN"; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the code in `latexmkrc` is executed before the command line arguments are obeyed.  You need something that is obeyed after the command line options setting the pdfmode are obeyed.

The only way I can see to do this within `latexmk` is to put your code in another rc file, say `latexmkrc-jobname`, and then invoke `latexmk` by, say

```
latexmk -pdflua -r latexmkrc-jobname file.tex
```

The contents of `latexmkrc-jobname` would be

```
if ($pdf_mode == 0) { $jobname = "%A-tex"; }
elsif ($pdf_mode == 1) { $jobname = "%A-pdftex"; }
elsif ($pdf_mode == 2) { $jobname = "%A-ps2pdf"; }
elsif ($pdf_mode == 3) { $jobname = "%A-dvipdf"; }
elsif ($pdf_mode == 4) { $jobname = "%A-luatex"; }
elsif ($pdf_mode == 5) { $jobname = "%A-xetex"; }
else { $jobname = "%A-UNKNOWN"; }
```

Comment: Well, I guess then it will be easier to set jobname in each engine call. Thanks for the hack!